# Carrierwave seems to be working as expected but photos won't show because of routingerror in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I've just completed my user photo album feature in my application and images upload to public/uploads folder, but he images aren't showing and this is coming up in my logs:

```
Started GET "/uploads/photo/image/11/thumb_admguk.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-19 00:42:26 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/photo/image/11/thumb_admguk.png"):
```

Would very much appreciate help figuring out this issue.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This caused my issue:
config.serve_static_assets = false

This was my solution:
config.serve_static_assets = true

Answer (score -2):

If you use Paperclip, try to add this in your Model:

```
has_attached_file :your_attribute_name,

:url => "/uploads/photo/image/:id/:basename.:extension",

:path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/photo/image/:id/:basename.:extension"
...
```

Comment: They wanted information about Carrierwave not Paperclip